# How to link to an image / file that is not in in the web assets

Tags: image, symfony, twig, src

I am having an issue with a basic document manager I am building for personal use

I have a method to upload documents locally and its stored in a folder called document-storage. This folder is stored in the main project folder: example this project is called

document management and the folder structure is like

document-management:

src:

web:

vendor:

document-storage:

The issue i am facing is i am storing all sorts of documents in this folder, they are just named the database id and then the .extension. I then store all the details in the database ect... This works perfect until i now want to start adding some previews to my documents. I thought i would start easy with an image. I wrote some code that looks like this

I have looked at the twig path methods such as absolute_url, path() and relative_path() but they don't look correct

Here is my code that I have so far

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>{{ file.filename }}</h1>
        <img src="{{ source ~ file.fullFileName }}" style="display: block">
    </div>
```

This renders a path that looks like this

```
<img src="C:\Users\Guest.Learner\Documents\document-manager\document-storage\1.jpg" style="display: block">
```

This is the correct file path however my image does not get displayed!

Is there something i am missing, ect something i am doing that i can not?

I expect to be able give the template the source and file name and then it be able to render the image. I deal with all logic else where.

Comment: Your image must be in the web folder, normally, only this folder is accessible via HTTP.

Comment: @COil means create an (absolute) URL like `http://www.example.com/folders/image.jpg` - Seeing this is a localproject it could be something like `http://localhost/project/folder/image.jpg`

Comment: @COil would there be any issue in storing all my documents in the web folder, If not this seems like a easier solution will less effect, i don't want to make life difficult for myself for when for example previewing a pdf or markdown later down the line.

Comment: the best practice is to craft an action in charge of returning a Response built from a file content... the action should then have a simple argument like the filename and it should know where to fetch it in the local fs

Answer (score 0):

My fix was i simple moved my documents to the web directory, however @Diego De Vitas answer may be the better solution for more advance systems